# What's the big-oh runtime for this code including break all?

Tags: python, big-o

```
def triples(A):
    result = -1
    for i in 0, 1, ..., n-1:
        for j in i+1, i+2, ..., n-1:
            for k in j+1, ..., n-1:
                if A[i] = A[j] and A[j] = A[k]:
                    result = i
                    break all
    return result
#A is an arbitrary array
```

For this, would the best case run time still be O(n^3)?
It looks to me that the if statement in the 3rd for loop will never evaluate to True, so the break all would never happen. Would I be correct in assuming this?

Also, if the break all were to be reached, would the best case run time be O(1)?

Comment: No. I actually couldn't find anything about break all :/
I was just wondering if someone could confirm if the break all would be reached at all in this code.
Also, my apologies for wording this weird. I have a final on this tomorrow in an introductory course and so far we've used big-Oh and run time interchangeably. We haven't really learned much else about other things that affect run time yet, although I'm aware they exist.

Comment: I'm going to assume `break all` is a pseudocode construct which just breaks out of every loop. (In that case, I'd have just rewritten the inner loop to `if ...: return i`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least formally, Big-O covers the worst case behavior of the algorithm, so unless you *know* that the `if` statement will be true at some point, you have to assume it will always be false, so the complexity is O(n<sup>3</sup>).

Informally, Big-O is often used for things like average cases as well as worst case. For example, if you were dealing with some fixed probability that the `if` statement would be true in any given case, you'd get O(n<sup>3</sup>) * probability. Since you discard all but the most significant term, that still ends up as O(n<sup>3</sup>).

If, however, there were an increasing probability of the `if` statement being true as the number of items increased, then that might decrease at least the average complexity. Just for example, if the numbers in `A` are chosen randomly from a limited range, then as the size of `A` increases, the chances of finding three identical items increases (and, of course, if `n` is more than triple the maximum possible value for an element, the chances of a duplicate turns into a certainty).

Simply assuming that the `break all` is reached at some point doesn't give O(1) complexity. To get O(1) complexity, you have to assure that the number of steps necessary to reach the `break all` is fixed--independent of the size of the array. If, for example, the third, fourth, and fifth elements always satisfy the condition, then you'd have O(1) complexity (though as noted in my comment to @Paxdiablo, you *normally* assume little or no knowledge of the possible inputs when doing complexity analysis). For what it's worth, the minimum complexity is signified with Big-Omega, *not* Big-O.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the code! I was really confused for a bit. So if I had to find the best case, I would assume the first three items in A were all the same. Would the complexity be O(1) in that case since break all will be reached immediately?

Comment: @user2893742: O(1) doesn't require that the first three items match, but does require that the match be found within a constant number of comparisons, regardless of the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is cubic, as stated, `O(n3)`, for both average case and worst case. The use of best case for complexity analysis is almost *never* used.

The complexity also has nothing to do with runtime. The runtime can be affected by complexity but it is not the same thing.

For example, the runtime of this code is "O(1)" if all elements are equal but the *complexity of the algorithm* doesn't care at all about that, it remains cubic.

The `break all` will be reached in this code as soon as you find three elements that are equal to each other and that *would* change best case runtime, but not complexity.

Comment: That's not entirely true. If part of the definition is that all elements in `A` are equal, then two, three or even ten nested loops won't change the fact that it's an O(1) algorithm (though, of course, you typically assume no knowledge of the inputs). Likewise, while the run time isn't determined entirely by the complexity, saying the complexity has "*nothing* to do with the runtime" is an exaggeration, to say the least.